# Make Amazon S3 Access Denied 403 fail gracefully with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Rails 4 app that uses Paperclip to read/write to my S3 bucket. When I show an object with an attachment (image), I display the image fine. When I show an object without an attachment, I display the `:default_url => "missing_image.png` which I store in `/assets/images`. This also works fine.

**The Problem**

I have had a few situations when there have been problems with S3 configuration (e.g., new bucket, bad credentials, wrong S3 permissions, etc.) and I get a 403 AccessDenied response. Then this happens, my app displays the little missing image rectangle, not the stored `:default_url` image (which I would prefer).

Is there a way to get Paperclip, or my object model, to return the `missing_image.png` stored in `/assets/images` when S3 responds with anything other than a 200?